# How to index when your data model is not fixed?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, indexing, elasticsearch

If I was building a system where I wanted to allow a dynamic data model (any objects/types), i.e. to allow schema evolution, how would I use something like elasticsearch to index data for easier querying? Is this possible or is it a case of choosing either a strict schema & indexing or dynamic schema & no indexing?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic data model"? EAV?

Comment: I wasn't aware of EAV to be honest. I was just considering the case where a system would allow developers to populate it with any object structure of their choosing, i.e. they might represent the same objects differently. If this were allowable would it still be possible to build indexes on this data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can index arbitrary data into ES. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html "The mapping itself is very flexible and is schema-free. New fields and objects will automatically be added to the mapping definition of the type specified"

As hinted at above, a  (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) "mapping" is an important concept relating to how data is stored and searched in ES. Certain functionality is only available on a "non default" mapping. Creating the relevant mapping does require knowing field names (and what you wish the mapping to be for those fields) So not all functionality is possible in a dynamic data model.

It is also worth nothing that there are limits to what updates can be done to a mapping, so again might create restrictions in a evolving data model.